# What is the best approach to use Disqus in a single page application?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, disqus, angularjs-directive, single-page-application

What is the best approach to use Disqus in a single page application?
I see that the angular js docs has implemented it successfully.

Currently our approach looks like is this in our AngularJS app, but it seems unstable, is hard to test, and loads wrong thread ids (the same thread gets loaded almost everywhere).

```
'use strict';

angular.module('studentportalenApp.components')
    .directive('disqusComponent',['$log', '$rootScope', function($log, $rootScope) {

    var _initDisqus = function _initDisqus(attrs)
    {
        if(window.DISQUS) {
            DISQUS.reset({
                reload: true,
                config: function () {
                    this.page.identifier = attrs.threadId;
                    this.disqus_container_id = 'disqus_thread';
                    this.page.url = attrs.permalinkUrl;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $log.error('window.DISQUS did not exist before directive was loaded.');
        }
    }

    //Destroy DISQUS bindings just before route change, to properly dispose of listeners and frame (postMessage nullpointer exception)
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
            if(window.DISQUS) {
                DISQUS.reset();
            }           
    });


    var _linkFn = function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            _initDisqus(attrs);
        }


    return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="disqus_thread"></div>',
        link: _linkFn
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also wanted to include Disqus on my AngularJS-powered blog. I found the existing solutions a bit unwieldy so I wrote my own directive:

```
.directive('dirDisqus', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            disqus_shortname: '@disqusShortname',
            disqus_identifier: '@disqusIdentifier',
            disqus_title: '@disqusTitle',
            disqus_url: '@disqusUrl',
            disqus_category_id: '@disqusCategoryId',
            disqus_disable_mobile: '@disqusDisableMobile',
            readyToBind: "@"
        },
        template: '<div id="disqus_thread"></div><a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>',
        link: function(scope) {

            scope.$watch("readyToBind", function(isReady) {

                // If the directive has been called without the 'ready-to-bind' attribute, we
                // set the default to "true" so that Disqus will be loaded straight away.
                if ( !angular.isDefined( isReady ) ) {
                    isReady = "true";
                }
                if (scope.$eval(isReady)) {
                    // put the config variables into separate global vars so that the Disqus script can see them
                    $window.disqus_shortname = scope.disqus_shortname;
                    $window.disqus_identifier = scope.disqus_identifier;
                    $window.disqus_title = scope.disqus_title;
                    $window.disqus_url = scope.disqus_url;
                    $window.disqus_category_id = scope.disqus_category_id;
                    $window.disqus_disable_mobile = scope.disqus_disable_mobile;

                    // get the remote Disqus script and insert it into the DOM
                    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                    dsq.src = '//' + scope.disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

### Advantages

The main advantage of this approach, I think, is that it keeps things simple. Once you have registered the directive with your app, you don't need to write any JavaScript or set any config values in your JavaScript. All configuration is handled by passing attributes in the directive tag like so:

```
<dir-disqus disqus-shortname="YOUR_DISQUS_SHORTNAME"
    disqus-identifier="{{ article.id }}"
    disqus-title="{{ article.title }}"
    ...>
</dir-disqus>
```

Also, you don't need to alter your index.html file to include the Disqus .js file - the directive will dynamically load it when it is ready. This means that all that extra .js will only get loaded on those pages that actually use the Disqus directive.

#### You can see the full source and documentation [here on GitHub](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus)

## Caveat

The above will only work properly when your site is in HTML5Mode, i.e. not using the "#" in your URLs. I am updating the code on GitHub so the directive will work when not using HTML5Mode, but be warned that you must set a hashPrefix of "!" to make "hashbang" URLs - e.g. `www.mysite.com/#!/page/123`. This is a limitation imposed by Disqus - see http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites

Comment: I suspect that this is not issue of your directive, but anyway each comment on my app rendering on each page with comment section.
I'm passing the unique identifier as an attribute and use ng-bind-ready, cause I'm using async data loading. Also I've checked that directive see my identifier. 
I'm using angular routes without HTML5 mode and without any hash prefix (only # sign).
Do you have any ideas how to solve it? I've added an issue on your directive github page.

Comment: Okay, we can continue this on the GitHub issue tracker. For anyone reading who has the same problem, here's the link: [https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/issues/1](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/issues/1)

Comment: Showing error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'disqus_shortname' of undefined`

Answer (score 4):

I know nothing about Disqus, but according to the AngularJS Documentation [source code](http://docs.angularjs.org/js/docs.js):

They bind a load function to afterPartialLoaded:

```
$scope.afterPartialLoaded = function() {
  var currentPageId = $location.path();
  $scope.partialTitle = $scope.currentPage.shortName;
  $window._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', currentPageId]);
  loadDisqus(currentPageId);
};
```

Then, they simply add the html to the page:

```
function loadDisqus(currentPageId) {
  // http://docs.disqus.com/help/2/
  window.disqus_shortname = 'angularjs-next';
  window.disqus_identifier = currentPageId;
  window.disqus_url = 'http://docs.angularjs.org' + currentPageId;

  // http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/
  (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = 'http://angularjs.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();

  angular.element(document.getElementById('disqus_thread')).html('');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how we solved it.

We load DISQUS in the body of index.html, and resets it whenever there is a directive using it.

Directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fooApp.directives')
    .directive('disqusComponent',['$window', '$log', function($window, $log) {

    var _initDisqus = function _initDisqus(scope)
    {
        if($window.DISQUS) {
                $window.DISQUS.reset({
                    reload: true,
                    config: function () {
                        this.page.identifier = scope.threadId;
                        this.disqus_container_id = 'disqus_thread';
                    }
                });
        }
        else
        {
            $log.error('window.DISQUS did not exist before directive was loaded.');
        }
    }

    var _linkFn = function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.html('<div id="disqus_thread"></div>');
            _initDisqus(scope);
        }


    return {
        replace: true,
        template: 'false',
        scope: {
            threadId: '@'
        },
        link: _linkFn
    };
}]);
```

This is how it can be tested:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: Disqus', function() {

  var element, $window, $rootScope, $compile;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('fooApp.directives', function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$window', function($delegate) {

            $delegate.DISQUS = {
                reset: jasmine.createSpy()
            };

            return $delegate;
        });
    });

    inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$window_) {
        $window = _$window_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $compile = _$compile_;
    });     

  });


  it('should place a div with id disqus_thread in DOM', function() {
    element = angular.element('<disqus-component></disqus-component>');
    element = $compile(element)($rootScope);
    expect(element.html()).toBe('<div id="disqus_thread"></div>');
  });

  it('should do a call to DISQUS.reset on load', function() {
    element = angular.element('<disqus-component thread-id="TESTTHREAD"></disqus-component>');
    element = $compile(element)($rootScope);

    var resetFn = $window.DISQUS.reset;

    expect(resetFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Comment: Are you sure this.disqus_container_id exists? It isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation. Also does this.disqus_category_id exist aswell? And shouldn't it be this.page.container_id?